# send docx file through httpwebrequest, target server is in Soap Envelope form. in C#

Tags: c#, soap-client, system.net.httpwebrequest

I trying to write a C# program to create a soap envelope request with attachment file in order to integrated with JAVA Axis Web Service.

below is my code.

```
public void Upload(string uri, string filePath, string ticket, string docTitle, string userName)
    {
        var _action = "https://dmsws-qa.sgp.st.com:20000/dmsservice/layer/CreateService";
        string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"{0}\";Content-ID=\"Doc1.docx\";\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
        string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        byte[] boundarybytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", _action);
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
        request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        request.Headers.Add("MIME-Version", "1.0");

        using(FileStream fileStream    = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            XmlDocument soapEnvelopeDocument = new XmlDocument();

            String _pathFiles = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("XMLRequest");
            XmlDocument xmlFile = new XmlDocument();
            xmlFile.Load(_pathFiles + "CreateService.xml");
            string finalXML = xmlFile.InnerXml.Replace("?ticket", ticket).Replace("?docTitle", docTitle).Replace("?docApprover", userName);
            LoggerUtility.LogInfo(finalXML);
            //xmlFile.Save(_pathFiles + "ConnectService.xml");

            soapEnvelopeDocument.LoadXml(finalXML);
            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
                string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, Path.GetFileName(filePath));   
                byte[] formbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
                requestStream.Write(formbytes, 0, formbytes.Length);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
                int bytesLeft = 0;

                while ((bytesLeft = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesLeft);
                }
                StreamReader stmreader = new StreamReader(requestStream);
                string webexception = stmreader.ReadToEnd();
                soapEnvelopeDocument.Save(requestStream);
            }

        }

        try
        {           
            using (HttpWebResponse response    = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) { }

            Console.WriteLine ("Success");
        }
        catch (WebException webex)
        {
            WebResponse errResp = webex.Response;
            using (Stream respStream = errResp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader webexceptionreader = new StreamReader(respStream);
                string webexception = webexceptionreader.ReadToEnd();

                LoggerUtility.LogException("DMSCreateServiceRequestError", webexception);

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is SOAP XML Create Service WSDL:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:doc="http://document.service.servicelayer.dms.cmcc.st"
  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body>
        <doc:create soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
              <documentType xsi:type="soapenc:string">st_work_instr</documentType>
              <matrixName xsi:type="soapenc:string">c_02400_08_Work Instructions</matrixName>
              <ticket xsi:type="soapenc:string">E9F491E565777832CE105AF781F035E2C080C0D8094E9FBE</ticket>
              <attrName xsi:type="cre:ArrayOf_xsd_anyType"
                    soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[]"
                    xmlns:cre="https://dmsws-qa.sgp.st.com:20000/dmsservice/layer/CreateService">
                    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">st_category</item>
                    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">title</item>
                    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">r_object_type</item>
                    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">st_approver</item>
                    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">st_responsible</item>
                    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">st_wi_department</item>
                    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">st_business_domain</item>
              </attrName>
              <attrValue xsi:type="cre:ArrayOf_xsd_anyType"
                    soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[]"
                    xmlns:cre="https://dmsws-qa.sgp.st.com:20000/dmsservice/layer/CreateService">
                    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">08-01-01</item>
                    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">seongtest01</item>
                    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">st_work_instr</item>
                    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">dmsupport1</item>
                    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">dmsupport1</item>
                    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">30</item>
                    <item xsi:type="xsd:string">09</item>
              </attrValue>
              <relChildNames xsi:type="cre:ArrayOf_xsd_anyType"
                    soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[]"
                    xmlns:cre="https://dmsws-qa.sgp.st.com:20000/dmsservice/layer/CreateService" />
              <relChildVersions xsi:type="cre:ArrayOf_xsd_anyType"
                    soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[]"
                    xmlns:cre="https://dmsws-qa.sgp.st.com:20000/dmsservice/layer/CreateService" />
              <fileName xsi:type="soapenc:string">Doc1.docx</fileName>
              <relNames xsi:type="cre:ArrayOf_xsd_anyType"
                    soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[]"
                    xmlns:cre="https://dmsws-qa.sgp.st.com:20000/dmsservice/layer/CreateService"/>
              <rendFileName xsi:type="soapenc:string"></rendFileName>
              <rendType xsi:type="soapenc:string">docx</rendType>
              <historyFileName xsi:type="soapenc:string"></historyFileName>
              <promoteOption xsi:type="soapenc:string">false</promoteOption>
        </doc:create>
  </soapenv:Body>
```

I able to attach file through SOAP UI application and return successful message. but in C# still not able. Please help.

Comment: What is the issue with your code? Do you get any errors? If so, post the exception details.

Comment: actually i not sure this code working or not, please advise